# How to access the ~/Library files to obtain the Terraria world and files directory?

Tags: games

Good Day everyone I am new to these forums and ubuntu myself. Now that Terraria is available for Linux I took the final jump from windows to linux since I don't play most of my games on windows anymore. But unfortunately I need to access the character folder since I didn't know how I looked it up and the ~/lib or user/lib/share Terraria would always be the answer which I searched and have no luck on finding.

Can anyone help me with this ~/Library issue? I just wanted to add a new character to my terraria collection

Comment: How have you installed the game?

Comment: I used steam after installing it on my ubuntu desktop 15.04

Comment: In stream you can define an installation folder for your games. Search in this folder and in your home folder. E.g. with `find $HOME -iname '*Terraria*'`

Comment: but i am trying to open the worlds folder and the character saves is the steam directories the proper path?

Answer (score 3):

You could search the folder of Terraria, e.g. via

```
find $HOME -iname '*Terraria*'
```

but:

---

The question was answered [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/24479/126120). My "answer" is a simple copy and paste. Please upvote [@lunboks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/9752/lunboks)s answer.

> If you are playing the Steam version with an Internet connection, you
>   can just let Steam do all that work for you by enabling cloud saving
>   for your character.
>
> [image: Terraria "move to cloud" button]
>
> Otherwise, your characters are stored in:
>
> - Windows: `<home folder>\Documents\My Games\Terraria\Players`
> - Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/Terraria/Players`
> - Linux: `~/.local/share/Terraria/Players`
>
> However, if you're using Steam cloud saves, the files will be in a
>   different location.
>
> `<Steam directory>/userdata/<Steam3 ID>/105600/remote/players`
>
> To copy a character, you will need both the `.plr` file and the folder
>   that are named like your character. Technically, only the file is
>   necessary, but the folder contains your minimap data.

Note, that `.local` is a hidden folder. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> in your filemanager or `ls -a` in your terminal to see hidden files.

Comment: I see but what is the location or directory of ~/.local that is what is confusing me the most I am trying viewing this through nautilus

Comment: `~` is only a shortcut for your home folder, e.g. `$HOME` or `/home/your_user_name`

Comment: so its home/local ohhh ok I pressed the home button and it shows desktop and those other things that the user has like downloads or do you mean somthing else? sorry for my confusion

Comment: If my answer helped you and your problem is solved, please click on the little tick at the left side of my answer, means "Yes, the answer is valid". **;)**

Answer (score 0):

My apologies everyone turns out the file location was hidden and I thought it was some crazy trick to see that file location but then it hit me and I looked up how to unhide files and my problem is solved thank you all for your help :)